# Cannot create a component in ember, I am met with an error every time

Tags: node.js, ember.js, broccolijs

To generate the component, I use

$ ember generate component my-component-name

But I am met with this long error:

> ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat
>   'C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\broccoli-3688mdxntFeSoJd5\out-114-broccoli_merge_trees_full_application/tests/index.html'
>       Expand stack frames
>       Broccoli Plugin: Funnel
>       ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\broccoli-3688mdxntFeSoJd5\out-114-broccoli_merge_trees_full_application/tests/index.html'
>   at Funnel (Funnel (test index)) -~- created here: -~- at Funnel.Plugin
>   (C:\Users\admin\datatable\node_modules\broccoli-plugin\index.js:7:31)
>   at new Funnel
>   (C:\Users\admin\datatable\node_modules\broccoli-funnel\index.js:57:10)
>   at DefaultPackager.processTestIndex
>   (C:\Users\admin\datatable\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\broccoli\default-packager.js:944:17)
>   at DefaultPackager.packageTests
>   (C:\Users\admin\datatable\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\broccoli\default-packager.js:906:26)
>   at EmberApp._legacyPackage
>   (C:\Users\admin\datatable\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\broccoli\ember-app.js:1729:46)
>   at EmberApp.toTree
>   (C:\Users\admin\datatable\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\broccoli\ember-app.js:1766:27)
>   at module.exports (C:\Users\admin\datatable\ember-cli-build.js:23:14)
>   at Builder.readBuildFile
>   (C:\Users\admin\datatable\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\models\builder.js:52:14)
>   at Builder.setupBroccoliBuilder
>   (C:\Users\admin\datatable\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\models\builder.js:66:22)
>   at new Builder
>   (C:\Users\admin\datatable\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\models\builder.js:32:10)
>   -~- (end) -~-
>                       Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\broccoli-3688mdxntFeSoJd5\out-114-broccoli_merge_trees_full_application/tests/index.html'
>           at Object.lstatSync (fs.js:863:3)
>           at symlinkWindows (C:\Users\admin\datatable\node_modules\symlink-or-copy\index.js:126:25)
>           at Function.symlinkOrCopySync [as sync] (C:\Users\admin\datatable\node_modules\symlink-or-copy\index.js:83:5)
>           at Funnel._copy (C:\Users\admin\datatable\node_modules\broccoli-funnel\index.js:494:19)
>           at Funnel.processFile (C:\Users\admin\datatable\node_modules\broccoli-funnel\index.js:477:8)
>           at Funnel.applyPatch [as _applyPatch] (C:\Users\admin\datatable\node_modules\broccoli-funnel\index.js:390:12)
>           at Funnel. (C:\Users\admin\datatable\node_modules\broccoli-funnel\index.js:344:10)
>           at Array.forEach ()
>           at Funnel.processFilters (C:\Users\admin\datatable\node_modules\broccoli-funnel\index.js:343:11)
>           at Funnel.build (C:\Users\admin\datatable\node_modules\broccoli-funnel\index.js:259:10)

My code works perfectly before generating a controller.

I am using broccoli-builder@2.0.1, node@v11.6.0, running on Windows 7

Add ons:

> amd-transform (unknown version) Couldn't find find info about this
>   package
>
> tests-server-middleware (unknown version) Couldn't find find info
>   about this package
>
> history-support-middleware (unknown version) Couldn't find find info
>   about this package
>
> live-reload-middleware (unknown version) Couldn't find find info about
>   this package
>
> broccoli-watcher (unknown version) Couldn't find find info about this
>   package
>
> broccoli-serve-files (unknown version) Couldn't find find info about
>   this package
>
> proxy-server-middleware (unknown version) Couldn't find find info
>   about this package
>
> testem-url-rewriter (unknown version) Couldn't find find info about
>   this package
>
> @ember/jquery (0.5.2) The default blueprint for ember-cli addons.
>
> @ember/optional-features (0.6.4) The default blueprint for ember-cli
>   addons.
>
> ember-addons-inspector (1.1.0) Inspect the addons included in your
>   Ember application or Ember addon
>
> ember-ajax (3.1.3) Service for making AJAX requests in Ember
>   applications.
>
> ember-cli-app-version (3.2.0) Adds App version number to Ember
>   Inspector Info Tab
>
> ember-cli-babel (7.2.0) Ember CLI addon for Babel
>
> ember-cli-dependency-checker (3.1.0) Ember CLI addon for detecting
>   missing npm and bower dependencies before executi g ember commands
>
> ember-cli-htmlbars (3.0.1) A library for adding htmlbars to ember CLI
>
> ember-cli-htmlbars-inline-precompile (1.0.5) Precompile inline
>   HTMLBars templates via ES6 tagged template strings
>
> ember-cli-uglify (2.1.0) JavaScript minification for Ember-CLI
>
> broccoli-asset-rev (2.7.0) broccoli asset revisions (fingerprint)
>
> ember-cli-sri (2.1.1) SRI generation for Ember CLI
>
> ember-cli-template-lint (1.0.0-beta.2) Lint your handlebars templates.
>
> ember-data (3.7.0) A data layer for your Ember applications.
>
> ember-export-application-global (2.0.0) Sets `window.MyAppName` up as
>   the application instance upon boot.
>
> ember-load-initializers (1.1.0) A tiny add-on to autoload your
>   initializer files in ember-cli.
>
> ember-maybe-import-regenerator (0.1.6) The default blueprint for
>   ember-cli addons.
>
> ember-resolver (5.0.1) The default modules based resolver for Ember
>   CLI.
>
> ember-source (3.7.0) A JavaScript framework for creating ambitious web
>   applications
>
> ember-welcome-page (3.2.0) Welcome page for Ember CLI applications
>
> loader.js (4.7.0) loader.js =========
>
> ember-qunit (3.5.3) QUnit helpers for testing Ember.js applications
>
> qunit-dom (0.8.4) High Level DOM Assertions for QUnit

I am also getting a message that ember-cli-babel 5.x has been deprecated. Not sure if its related.

Comment: Looking aside at the error messages, it says you’re generating a component, not a controller

Comment: Sorry, thats what I meant to put

Answer (score 5):

does `ember g component my-name` result in the same thing?

I'd debug like this:

```
rm -rf node_modules tmp dist
npm install
npm uninstall -g ember-cli
npm install -g ember-cli@whatever-version
ember g component my-name
```

if that doesn't work, if you need to get unblocked, here is what it would give you:

```
import Component from '@ember/component';

export default Component.extend({

});
```

depending on your ember version, of course.

Comment: I was able to fix my issue by deleting the tests folder. If the error occurs again, I will try this and update with the results.

Answer (score 2):

Fixed this by deleting my tests folder, by recommendation of: https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli-test-loader/issues/24#issuecomment-264444621

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to delete tmp folder and node modules.The problem usually lies in tmp folder with broccoli but to be sure delete node modules too. Then update your node js(11.9) and npm install to install everything of your pakcage.json. Then try again to generate a component.

***npm -g rm*** to remove node modules.

Comment: Still being hit with the same error. Also my tmp folder is empty (I still deleted it though). Any other ideas?